# Is there a way to read a csv file in hdfs into a python dataframe using insecureclient in a jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, hdfs

I have a csv file located on hdfs in a remote server.
I want to read the csv file into a pandas dataframe using insecureclient, however I keep getting an error

1st attempt:
code:

```
from hdfs import InsecureClient
client_hdfs = InsecureClient('hdfs://host:port', user=user)
with client_hdfs.read('path/to/csv.csv') as reader:
    print(reader)
```

error:

> InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for
> 'host:port:path/to/csv.csv'

I have verified that the path is correct by running 'hdfs -ls path/to/csv.csv' on the server and viewing the file there and have obtained the host name by running 'uname -n' on the server.

2nd attempt (created a new test file with the contents "this is a test file" and placed in same hdfs location and tried to read):

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("myFirstApp").setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

path = "hdfs://host:port/path/to/textfile.txt"
df = sc.textFile(path)
df.first()
```

Error:

> runs indefinitely without ever returning result

Comment: Why not use pyspark?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `hdfs://` with `http://`?

Comment: @MattL. if I do it just gives a time out error

Answer (score 0):

The module you're using connects to WebHDFS (using `http` protocol), not HDFS Namenode port (`hdfs://` protocol)

Docs - https://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#instantiating-a-client

PySpark, on the other hand, does allow connecting over `hdfs://` + You should use Spark dataframes, not Pandas directly - https://databricks.com/blog/2021/10/04/pandas-api-on-upcoming-apache-spark-3-2.html

Comment: Edited answer to include pyspark attempt

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure you're using the correct host/port? Do you need to use local master if you have a Hadoop cluster (which would include YARN)?

Comment: can you confirm you ran the pyspark code exactly as I have it and it did indeed work for you?

Comment: I mean, I use a real HDFS endpoint and my namenode port, and yes, it works fine on my Mac

Comment: the host is the result given after entering uname -u into the (unix-based) server. this is the only way to derive host name as far as I know. As for the port I am sure that is correct. Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'local/master' for the hadoop cluster? are you referring to the file path?

Comment: You should use `hostname -f`, or use `ifconfig` to get the host / IP. But you still need to know the correct port, which would be defined in the `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR/core-site.xml` file, if it is not the default. And no, `.setMaster("yarn")` instead of local

Comment: seems to have been a firewall issue on my companies end.